# How to run a clean up when terminating Python script

Tags: python, multiprocessing, terminate

I have a python script that does some jobs. I use `multiprocessing.Pool` to have a few workers do some commands for me.

My problem is when I try to terminate the script. When I press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, I would like, that every worker immediately cleans up its experiment (which is some custom code, or actually even a subprocess command, not just releasing locks or memory) and stops.

I know that I can catch <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> with the signal handler. How can I make all current running workers of a `multiprocessing.Pool` to terminate, still doing their cleanup command?

`Pool.terminate()` will not be useful, because the processes will be terminated without cleaning up.

Answer (score 2):

How about trying the [atexit](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html) standard module?

It allows you to register a function that will be executed upon termination.

Comment: No, it says: "Note: the functions registered via this module are not called when the program is killed by a signal". And I need to have it killed by signal

Comment: By 'killed by a signal' I think it means killed by a signal that you don't explicitly catch and handle yourself. If you're using the Python signal handler to catch the Ctrl-C and handle it yourself, you can do what you like in your handler.

Answer (score 1):

Are you working with Unix?  If yes, why not catch SIGTERM in the subprocesses?  In fact, the documentation of `Process.terminate()` reads:

```
Terminate the process. On Unix this is done using the SIGTERM signal
```

(I have not tested this.)